Can a pure mathematics PhD dissertation consist largely of incomplete and/or failed attempts at theorems (with an overarching theme)?
The Question:

Can a pure mathematics PhD dissertation consist largely of incomplete and/or failed attempts at theorems (with an overarching theme)?

Background:
I have just started my third year of a PhD in group theory here in the UK, where PhDs last at most four years of study; I don't have the funding for a fourth year.  I have about five theorems so far, two of which are kind of small - more like lemmas - and only one that I can say makes a conceptual difference to the literature, despite being relatively easy to prove.
There's a conjecture I've been working towards for months now that, if proven, would be the meat of my dissertation.  Research is unpredictable.  I could fail to prove it in time.  I have tried hard to prove it; very hard, in fact - but to no avail.
I could modify the scope of my research.  I could look at particular cases of the conjecture.  I could try proving something else.
That's not the point.
The point of this question is: what if I fail to prove anything big enough for a PhD dissertation?
Could I put together all the things I've tried during this project then claim the resulting document as a dissertation, and "get away with it"?
The research fits into an overarching theme.  I feel like I have valuable things to say about these attempts.
Thoughts:
A PhD is about a "significant, original contribution to knowledge".  Failed or incomplete attempts at theorems are still worth sharing if only to warn, guide, and inform future explorers of the area about my approaches.
After all, I have gathered sufficient data for a realistic conjecture. It could be of use to the community.

I think you can get a PhD with this, but you should ask your advisor and potential examiners.  Standards differ in different places.  As to whether you can get an academic job afterwards... - well you should still ask your advisor.

You get a PhD if your adviser and your committee sign off on what you have done and written. You need to ask these people what they think, not us.
